# No muestra por alert el item seleccionado de un select

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un select que lo cargo con los datos que traigo de mi BD, tengo una función javascritp a la cual le envío como parámetro el elemento de la lista que selecciono, pero luego en la función hago un alert para mostrar lo que llega pero siempre llega vacío. No me aparece nada en el alert.

**Código PHP y HTML**

```
<select class="custom-select form-control" id="tipo" onchange="cargarCategoria(this)">
    <option selected></option>
    <?php
        require ('conexion/Conexion.php');
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT tipo FROM formacion";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
           echo '<option value="">'.$fila["tipo"].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

**Código JavaScript**

```
function cargarCategoria(dato)
{
    alert(dato.value);//Este es el valor que llega vacio, deberia ser el elemento seleccionado del select.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'consultas/consultarCategoria.php',
        data: 'tipo='+dato,
        success: function(resp){
            $('#categoria').html(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: te llega vacío por que el value que generas esta vacío mira esta linea `echo '<option value="">'.$fila["tipo"].'</option>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviando que puede que no se obtenga el valor "value" del this select de esa forma... Te replico el codigo que pasas en el option. El value esta vacio asi que al acceder a ese valor puede que te lo pinte pero como es vacio no lo ves, o que te lo ponga como undefined por que lo inicializas con un conjunto vacio.

```
echo '<option value="">'.$fila["tipo"].'</option>'
```

Prueba esto y vuelve a imprimir, sino funciona mira el this con un "console.log"

```
echo '<option value=".$fila["tipo"]">'.$fila["tipo"].'</option>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Si usas jQuery, porque no lo manejas con un `.on` en lugar de asignarle el `onchange` en el `select`

Podría ser algo así

```
$('#tipo').on('change',function(){

    alert(
      $(this).val()
    );

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'consultas/consultarCategoria.php',
        data: 'tipo='+dato,
        success: function(resp){
            $('#categoria').html(resp);
        }
    });

});
```

De esta manera, el alert mostraría el `val()` de tu `select` al cambiar.

Un tema importante que no había notado, es que en tu `while` estas asignando a todos tus `option` un `value=""`

```
echo '<option value="">'
```

Por lo que efectivamente, siempre va a devolver `""` el frontend, porque la opción tiene un valor vacío!

Answer (score 1):

cuando das click a un elemento de un select lo que llegaría por parámetro no es lo que está dentro de las etiquetas `option` sino lo que está en su value.

Reemplaza

```
echo '<option value="">'.$fila["tipo"].'</option>';
```

Por

```
echo '<option value="'.$fila["tipo"].'">'.$fila["tipo"].'</option>';
```